# Quickly filter parent NSManagedObjects based on possible property in child object

Tags: objective-c, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobject, nsset

I'm working on a project that requires some fairly complex filtering. I have a `Race` NSManagedObject that has a number of `Car` objects attached. The `Car` can have multiple `Position` objects. For a given race, I need to get a list of all of the cars but they need to be ordered differently based on if the race is running or not. If the race hasn't started, they need to be ordered by `Car.number` (simple). If the race is running, they need to be ordered by their current position. The difficulty is that the position retrieved can't be the latest one in the set, but the latest within a specific range and there may not be a position at all (i.e. if the car is out of the race).

The sorting is all done and I have some code working that allows me to set a `currentPosition` property on my `Car` based on retrieving the full set of positions for the car and then using `filteredSetUsingPredicate:` and `valueForKeyPath:` to retrieve the maximum time. The issue with this is that it is quite slow and this needs to be very quick (as it happens every second). I had wrapped it within `dispatch_async` but that caused occassional freezes as the NSManagedObjects aren't threadsafe.

What I ideally need is a way to get an NSArray of `Car` objects that have `Car.currentPosition` optionally set to the latest `Position` if applicable (which is determined by getting the last `Position.time` within the last 10 seconds if it exists). I can then sort the returned array myself based on the `Car.currentPosition.position` property and do the other bits I need to do (i.e. moving those without a currentPosition to a separate list of non finishers).

Below is the (slow) code I have so far. I either need a way to speed this up (some way of using dispatch_async without causing thread issues) or a better way of doing my initial fetch from CoreData so this can be done on that side which I presume would be faster.

Current code:

```
    - (void)performFetchWithCallback:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
    {
        NSError *error;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        }

        NSMutableArray *cars = [NSMutableArray array];

        BOOL isRacing = NO;
        for (Car *car in _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
            Position *position = nil;
            NSSet *carPositions = [[car valueForKey:@"positions"] copy];
            if (carPositions && currentTime > 0) {
                NSSet *positions = [carPositions filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"time < %@ && time > %@", @(currentTime), @(currentTime-10)]];
                if (positions.count > 0) {
                    NSNumber *time = [positions valueForKeyPath:@"@max.time"];
                    for (Position *p in positions) {
                        if ([p.time isEqual:time]) {
                            position = p;
                            isRacing = YES;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            car.currentPosition = position;
            [cars addObject:car];
        }

        self.allCars = cars;

        if (completionBlock) {
            completionBlock();
        }
    }

    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
    {
        if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
            return _fetchedResultsController;
        }

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"raceIdentifier = %@", _race.identifier];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:40];

        NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Racing"];
        self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;

        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
```

There is an ivar named `currentTime` which contains the number of seconds since the race started - this is used to determine what positions should be shown (as positions can be saved a long time in advance).

Models:

**Car**

- raceIdentifier (NSNumber - used to limit Car to a Race)
- number (NSNumber - The starting number of the car - this is used to sort the Cars when race hasn't started)
- positions (NSSet of Position objects)

**Position**

- time (NSNumber - the time, in seconds, of this position update)
- position (NSNumber - the position of the car in the race i.e. 1st)

Comment: Quite a dilemma you've got yourself! When you tried putting your fetches/computations in a background thread, did you try & have success with saving the sorted car IDs in the background thread, passing that set of IDs through to the main thread via a callback, and then re-fetching the `NSManagedObjects` in the main thread based on those IDs? In thread fetching issues, passing around `NSIntegers` have saved my bacon before,

Comment: I literally wrapped everything after `performFetch:` in `dispatch_async()` and then did a `dispatch_async` to the main thread when running `completionBlock()`. I didn't try passing IDs around as I'm not sure if that would help in this instance - I need to do the sort based on the `Car.Position.time` so I'd need the whole object in the background thread unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: I'll whip up a bit of code and post it as an answer — I speak better in code.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for what may be an oversimplification, but in a nutshell, this is what should (could?) work.

```
- (void)performFetchWithCallback:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
    // Use a dictionary instead; you'll want to set instance variables on your cars in the main
    // thread
    __block NSMutableDictionary *carDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,NULL), ^{
        // Perform a non-resultsController fetch with a background context, using the 
        // car, number, race identifier NSFetchRequest below

        // Then your for (car in fetchedResults) computation loop, but use a
        // mutable dictionary (carDict) instead of an array, and store car IDs as
        // your keys, and their current position as their values

        dispatch_async(main, ^{
            // Here, fetch your cars into your fetched results controller based on a
            // predicate of the carDict keys you stored (id IN %@), then do a quick
            // for (car in fetchedResults) loop and assign those currentPosition values here
            if (completionBlock) completionBlock();
        });
    });
}
```

I usually work with [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) when dealing with contexts in other threads, as [it simplifies it](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord#finding-from-a-different-context) a *great* deal; call me spoiled.

Comment: So within the `async` I'd create a new managed object context and do a fetch on that, store the results in a dictionary, and then use those on the main thread? Wouldn't the `Position` objects stored in the dictionary cause issues when used on the main thread as they were retrieved from the background? Also, what would be the difference in getting `Position` from the background but not the `Car` objects?